# Load EF entity with sibling includes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle11g

I have to load an entity from the database and I need to eagerly load into that entity almost all the relations from the database. I tried using `Include` but without success. Here is the code:

```
var thingy = _ctx.MASTERANDCOMMANDER
            .Include(x => x.RED) 
            .Include(x => x.RED.Select(y => y.RED_ONE)) 
            //.Include(x => x.RED.Select(y => y.RED_TWO)) 
            .Include(x => x.GREEN) 
            .Include(x => x.GREEN.Select(y => y.GREEN_ONE))
            .Include(x => x.GREEN.Select(y => y.GREEN_ONE.Select(z => z.GREEN_ONE_BIG))) 
            //.Include(x => x.GREEN.Select(y => y.GREEN_TWO)) 
            //.Include(x => x.GREEN.Select(y => y.GREEN_THREE)) 
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == "someId");
```

If I uncomment any of those includes, the app throws: 
System.Exception: Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 doesn't support APPLY

Using EntityFramework 6 and Oracle 11.2.0.2.0.
I cannot upgrade EF nor Oracle.

How can I load the relations from GREEN_TWO, etc. into thingy?

**Edit:** All relations shown are one to many from left to right. Examples:

- RED (1 to *) RED_ONE
- GREEN_ONE (1 to *) GREEN_ONE_BIG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `Join` instead of `Include`, e. g.:

```
var thingy = _ctx.MASTERANDCOMMANDER
    .Join(RED, x => x.MASTERANDCOMMANDERID, x => REDID, (m, r) => m)...etc...
```

and so on, where you need to get `RED` from your database as another single entity.

Comment: Tried this (actually using the linq syntax) and it works... but if any item has the relation empty it returns an empty object, so I'm forced to use left joins... and those are ugly on C#

Answer (score 0):

maybe using .ThenInclude() would help

```
var thingy = _ctx.MASTERANDCOMMANDER
                .Include(x => x.RED) 
                .ThenInclude(red => red.RED_ONE)
                .Include(x => x.GREEN) 
                .ThenInclude(green => green.GREEN_ONE)
                .ThenInclude(greenOne => greenOne.GREEN_ONE_BIG)            
                .Where(x => x.ID == "someId").SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: This version of EF doesn't have that method =(